# Selenium "xpath" giving wrong value

Tags: ruby, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I might be doing anything wrong,can anyone correct me where it is.

I have set up a code for some selections:

```
to_select = wbs.cells(rows,7).value
driver.find_element(:xpath,"//table[contains(@id,'searchTable')]/tbody/tr[contains(@code,to_select)]/td").click
```

But the above selecting some other values.

When I tried the below,working fine.

```
driver.find_element(:xpath,"//table[contains(@id,'searchTable')]/tbody/tr[contains(@code,"PowerSelect")]/td").click
```

***HTML***

```
<tr id="19692" code="PowerSelect" onclick="selectPopupField('19692','popupConditionCode','popupConditionId','conditionPopupDiv');return false;"> <td>PowerSelect</td></tr>
```

Comment: driver.find_element(:xpath,"//table[contains(@id,'searchTable')]/tbody/tr[contains(@code,#{to_select})]/td").click  this might be helpful

Comment: Let me give it a try. Meanwhile you put it as your answer. And why `#` needed - explain please.

Comment: Yes! you are right that works with a bit modification - `driver.find_element(:xpath,"//table[contains(@id,'searchTable')]/tbody/tr[contai‌​ns(@code,'#{to_select}')]/td").click` - you can put it as your answer,I will accept it.

Comment: My pleasure to help you.. I don't know much about ruby but, I found something wrong with inserting variable in xpath. anyway Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
driver.find_element(:xpath,"//table[contains(@id,'searchTable')]/tbody/tr[contai‌​ns(@code,'#{to_select}')]/td").click
```

this might be helpful.